# Collect into Guava's ListMultiMap using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava, collectors

I am trying to collect into a ListMultiMap using java 8 without using the forEach operation.

If I were to write the code in Java 7, it will be something like this:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> result = ArrayListMultimap.create();
     for(State state: states) {
      for(City city: state.getCities()) {
        result.put(state.getName(), city.getName());
      }
    }
```

I found online a [website](http://codingjunkie.net/guava-and-java8-collectors/) that talks about creating your own collectors to use in scenarios such as this one. 
I used this implementation for the collector. I then wrote the following code:

```
     ListMultimap<String, String> result = states
        .stream()
        .flatMap(state -> state.getCities().stream()
            .map(city -> {
              return new Pair(state, city);
            }))
        .map(pair -> {
          return new Pair(pair.first().getName(), pair.second().getName()));
        })
        .collect(MultiMapCollectors.listMultimap(
                    Pair::first,
                    Pair::second
                )
        );
```

But at the collect level, I can only pass just one parameter, and I can seem to find a way to pass two parameters.
Following the example from the website, I understood that to use both, I need to store a "pair" in the multimap such as the following:

```
ArrayListMultimap<String, Pair> testMap = testObjectList.stream().collect(MultiMapCollectors.listMultimap((Pair p) -> p.first().getName()));
```

However this is not what I'm looking for, I want to collect into ListMultimap using the state's name and the city's name using java 8's collector (and no forEach).

Can someone help me with that ?
Thank you!

Comment: The code behind that link doesn't look to sound; Raw types, unchecked casts and unneeded type variable for the accumulator.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for pointing that out ! 
I thought that it was sound because I found a lot of other websites with similar implementations. Thank you !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`ImmutableListMultimap.flatteningToImmutableListMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#flatteningToImmutableListMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

```
return states.stream()
   .collect(flatteningToImmutableListMultimap(
      State::getName,
      state -> state.getCities().stream().map(City::getName)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You *could* create a custom collector for that (note that Louis Wasserman's answer will do a forEachOrdered internally, you can't really escape a forEach either internally or externally).

```
 ListMultimap<String, String> list = states.collect(Collector.of(ArrayListMultimap::create, (multimap, s) -> {
        multimap.putAll(s.getName(), s.getCities().stream().map(City::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }, (multi1, multi2) -> {
        multi1.putAll(multi2);
        return multi1;
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was looking for something similar to Louis Wasserman's answer, but you gave me an pretty nice idea that I need for something else by saying "You could create a custom collector".